# How to configure msal.js to use two Authorities (Apps) (AAD & AADB2C)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Is it possible to configure msal to work with two different apps simultaneously? Or perhaps is it possible to have two instances running in parallel on the same Single Page Application SPA?

Specifically, I have a business app that is accessed by both B2C users and Corporate users. The business prefers that the Corporate users be able to log into the app without the need to create an additional B2C account (and using a federated B2C sign-in type). This would mean that I need an app in the B2C tenant and the Corporate tenant, and my single page application app would be protected by either app for any given user.

In other words, if you follow this link:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial#chapter-1-sign-in-a-user-to-your-application

it gives instructions for how to sign in with Azure AD, and how to sign in with Azure AD B2C. But how would I go about doing both at the same time?

Comment: refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: @MohitGanorkar Unless I misunderstood, this requires replicating the identity in B2C which is not desired. (As i can't just sign-in an AAD user without first doing a B2C sign-up for them)

Comment: Turns out the app was a Web App and not SPA, so we couldn't use the library anyways. Ended up doing the calls by hand for both.

Comment: That link doesn’t require replicating identities, it just does by default. In custom policies you don’t need to. It is the correct solution to this issue.